# What is installed when I install ros-melodic-desktop-full?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [this guide](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) in order to install ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. Specifically, I installed the "full version" by issuing the command `sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full`. What exactly is installed with this command? Is e.g. `rospkg` (or `python-rospkg`) and `rosbag` installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317266/what-is-installed-when-i-install-ros-melodic-desktop-full?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2019-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ChriMo's answer is ok, but the official definition of the contents of those meta-packages can be found in [REP 150](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0150.html): *ROS Melodic and Newer Metapackages*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-02**:
A related post: #q256493.